# How to change format of a duration field value in serializer?

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

I have a model called Task with field delay which is a duration field.

```
class Task:
    delay = models.DurationField(timedelta(seconds=0))
```

and a serializer as below.

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('id', 'delay')
```

On creation of instance using serializer, I pass data such as `{delay: 30}` expecting seconds to be passed.

Instance is created as expected. However on retrieval, I get below result.

```
[
    {
        "delay": "00:00:00.000060",
    },
    {
        "delay": "00:00:00.000050",
    },
    {
        "delay": "00:00:00.000060",
    }
]
```

I am trying to get delay value in serializer in integer format only. For example:

```
[
    {
        "delay": 60,
    },
    {
        "delay": 50,
    },
    {
        "delay": 60
    }
]
```

I am not willing to change field name "delay" in either write or read serializer. How can I achieve the requirement ?

Answer (score 5):

I solved it by using a [serializer method](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) to customize duration field serialization, so it can return the value wanted in seconds.

Your code should look like this:

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    delay = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('id', 'delay')

    def get_delay(self, obj):
        return obj.delay.total_seconds()
```

*NOTE: Maybe you will need to create different serializers classes for **create** and **retrieve** objects, since serializer method only work for read only fields*

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I would guess the integer is interpreted as microseconds and you need to send your seconds as a string

```
{"delay": "60"}
```

If you want to send the seconds as integer (in the json) you pbly need to create a custom Field. The easiest way would be to inherit from `DurationField()` and adapt the behaviour to your needs.

Comment: Thanks. Can you think of an easy solution without creating custom model field ?

Comment: Try the timedelta as a string, I don't think timedelta is intendet to be used with an integer, I think what you are actually doing is using a fallback for the DurationField and since the default `resolution` for a timedelta field is microseconds your input value is interpredet as microseconds.

You can see that in your examples, what you are getting is a string which represents a `timedelta`.